# How to make the bot clone an emote into the server

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im trying to make the bot get the url from an emote that is outside the server and clone it into the server its in it goes like that:
?cloneemoji "emote"

```
    @commands.command(aliases = ['ce'])
    async def cloneemoji(self, ctx, *, emoji: discord.Emoji):
        await self.upload.Server(url='{}'.format(emoji.url))
```

Comment: are you using a webhook to send the emoji?

Comment: No, Should i be using a webhhook?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of which most bots use to send an emoji on behalf of author of the command,

It simply creates a Webhook and displays as a bot, but keeps the username and profile picture of the user using the command, many bots such as NQN use this method, so hope this gets you what you need

```py
@client.command()
async def emoji(ctx, *, emojis=None):
        if emojis== None:
                await ctx.send(
                    f'Please provide a message or emoji!')
                return

        webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name=ctx.author.name)
        await webhook.send(
            str(message),
            username=ctx.author.name,
            avatar_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        webhooks = await ctx.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in webhooks:
                await webhook.delete()
```